# Login issue in Logshipping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have configured log shipping in my primary serverA and secondary serverB.

Everything works fine until I bring the standby database online.

Users are not able to login to the secondary serverB database (which is on the secondary server, which is brought online)

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What is the error you are getting,while users are logging in

Comment: logshipping is not server level,may be you gave some one has access primary DB but not secondary ?

Comment: That is classic case of orphaned users. In  Loshipping you restore database which only moves users and this causes orphaned users on secondary databases. Run `sp_change_users_login @action=report` to list all orphaned users of a database

Answer (score 5):

LogShipping does not replicate server level objects such as logins, so your user will be unable to log in to the secondary server when you switch roles.

You can migrate existing logins using the [sp_help_revlogin](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/918992) stored procedure, keeping SIDs and passwords for SQL authenticated logins.